# Remove dynamic attribute in hybris through backoffice

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

When the dynamic attribute is removed from the ***items.xmls***, hybris reports an error because the attribute handler Spring bean don't exist. This error usually prevents saving models of the Hybris type which owned the attribute. Even after the bean declaration and attribute are removed, hybris still complains about the existance of the reference to a bean.

**How to remove DynamicAttributeHandler from the DB through backoffice in Hybris?**

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way to do this is to go to backoffice -> Types -> search for your type -> Properties and then remove the property and save.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove your custom attribute from the `Attributedescriptors` table.

Use a direct SQL statement :

```
DELETE FROM attributedescriptors WHERE (QualifierInternal ='attributename')
```

Comment: If your tests fail because of a phantom dynamic handler, check the `junit_attributedescriptors` table. In our case the DynHandler attribute descriptor was not removed from the junit table.